# SQL create concatenated string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called service entry and Im trying to create a concatenated string.

```
ID  ServiceEntryID  PartID  Comment  ServiceTypeIDs  PartDescription
1        2           54      xyz      1               hellothere
2        2           22                               howdy
3        33          54      uhu      1               xyz
```

**Desired String format**

PartID~PartDescription~ServiceTypeIDs~Comment

**Desired String value**

so for service entry ID column with value 2:

54 ~ hellothere ~ 1 ~ xyz | 22 ~ howdy ~ null ~ |

for service entry ID column with value 33:

33 ~ xyz ~ 1 ~ uhu

If the entry does not have a comment then I do not add a null for it whereas if servicetypeids are empty then I will add a null

Comment: just wrap each string to concat in a coalesce(comment,'null') statement.

Comment: thnaks all for your comments and answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
     ServiceEntryID,
     STUFF(
         (SELECT '|' + CAST(PartID AS VARCHAR(5)) + '~' +
                       PartDescription  + '~' +
                       COALESCE(CAST(ServiceTypeIDs AS VARCHAR(5)), 'NULL')  + '~' +
                       COALESCE(Comment, 'NULL')
          FROM TableName
          WHERE ServiceEntryID = a.ServiceEntryID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS ResultList
FROM TableName AS a
WHERE ServiceEntryID = 2
GROUP BY ServiceEntryID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfc69/10)
- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfc69/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select   coalesce(partID,'NULL') +'~'+ 
coalesce(PartDescription,'NULL') +'~'+ 
 coalesce(ServiceTypeIDs,'NULL') +'~'+
 coalesce(Comment,'NULL') as DesiredStringFormat
FROM yourTableName
```

The above will substitute the word 'NULL' when any field is NULL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx